# node.js: howto start a dos batch in an external process

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file, cmd

Currently I am using this code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  ls = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'D:/test_bat.cmd']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  myOutputChannel.append('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  myOutputChannel.append('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  myOutputChannel.append('child process exited with code ' + code + '\n');
});
```

This works well for batch files not using any input from the user.

But if the batch requires any user input, e.g. it has pause to wait, and user must enter return to continue, the child process never ends. myOutputChannel is a write only device and is not able to process user input.

That why I need to start the batch as external dos window from the node.js code. Is there a way to watch at the node.js code when the dos window is closed and get the exit code of the batch. Does anyone has a clue how to do that?

Comment: Did you try just writing to the `ls.stdin` stream when it's asking for input? Or just calling `ls.stdin.end()` if the child process is expecting input from stdin at startup and you don't want/need to pass any such input?